# Is there anyway to replace a bookmark with a space using the body_replace_text_at_bkm from the officer R package?

Tags: r, officer

I'm trying to use officer::body_replace_text_at_bkm to replace a bookmark in a Word Document with an empty space.

I have a Word document template with a bookmark like the one below.

[image: Word Doc Template]

I used the code below to replace the "space" bookmark with an empty space.

```
library(officer)
doc <- read_docx(path =  "Test_Add_Space_Template.docx" )
officer::body_replace_text_at_bkm(doc, 'space', ' ')
print(doc, 'Test_Add_space.docx')
```

However, when I run the code above, no space is added to the bookmark.

[image: Word Doc Output]

I was wondering if there is a way to replace bookmarks with empty spaces, and if not, if there was another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, realized I needed to use Unicode. In this case "\u2008" enters a punctuation space.

```
library(officer)
doc <- read_docx(path =  "Test_Add_Space_Template.docx" )
officer::body_replace_text_at_bkm(doc, 'space', '\u2008')
print(doc, 'Test_Add_space.docx')
```

You can find a list of Unicode characters and punctuation at
https://unicode.org/charts/nameslist.

In R, you use can use \u as an escape character. In another case, I needed an en-dash, which is "2013" in Unicode, so I used "\u2013" as the value for my bookmark.